# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /root/Desktop/generator/dump.php on line 13

Tags: php

My question is I don't see why it won't actually work?I am also new to php so I am learning this PHP. I do not know why it is an unexpected T_VARIABLE and I'm assuming it means " $ "

```
<?php
   include('database.class.php');
   $sql = new Database(NULL);

   $ids = $sql->select('*', '`ids` ORDER BY `UserId` ASC', NULL, NULL, NULL, true, true);

   $dump = array();
   foreach($ids as $index=>$id);
        $dump[] = $id['UserId'].' | REGLINK - http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/register.php?UserId='.$id['UserId'].'&k2='.$id['k2'].'&mode=1'

   $DumpFile= 'ids.txt';

   if(file_exists($DumpFile)) {
        unlink($DumpFile);
   }
   file_put_contents($DumpFile, implode("\r\n", $dump));
   die(count($dump).' ids were dumped into the list.'."\n");
?>
```

Comment: You have missed semicolon `;` after `'&mode=1'`.

Comment: i'm asking for help on my code not a reference guide really.

Comment: It is not only for you. It is for those, who may see this thread. SO is not a debugger tool. Still, check my second comment.

Comment: @LexiSchmitt Put the semicolon as CORRUPT said, and let us know if it helped

Comment: Well it's now saying it has a PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: id in /root/Desktop/generator/dump.php on line 11 *edit sorry about my rude comment

Comment: @LexiSchmitt  Undefined variable means, that something is wrong with $ids. var_dump($ids); before foreach. What does it say?

Comment: I guess i did not post the full error sorry,     PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: arrReturn in /root/Desktop/generator/database.class.php on line 127
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /root/Desktop/generator/dump.php on line 10
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: id in /root/Desktop/generator/dump.php on line 11
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: id in /root/Desktop/generator/dump.php on line 11
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: id in /root/Desktop/generator/dump.php on line 11

Comment: You should totally read the link @CORRUPT sent you on his first comment its a reference of what the most common errors in PHP mean, and it list both of the errors you have mentioned it would be a great reference guide for you to keep for when u get other errors.

Comment: Well you haven't posted `/root/Desktop/generator/database.class.php` as that is where one of the errors is.

Comment: SO is NOT your debugger tool. Find a _specific_ problem, try to solve it yourself first, then bring the problem and your solution here.

Comment: is there a way i can close my account on this website? it's no use to me because most of the "help" or answers are irrelevant

Comment: See how to delete an account - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/184631 And http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Answer (score 1):

you have to put semicolon   **;** after **&mode=1'**
like :

```
$ids = $sql->select('*', '`ids` ORDER BY `UserId` ASC', NULL, NULL, NULL, true, true);

$dump = array();
foreach($ids as $index=>$id);
        $dump[] = $id['UserId'].' | REGLINK - http://xat.com/web_gear/chat/register.php?UserId='.$id['UserId'].'&k2='.$id['k2'].'&mode=1';

$DumpFile= 'ids.txt';

if(file_exists($DumpFile)) {
        unlink($DumpFile);
}
file_put_contents($DumpFile, implode("\r\n", $dump));
die(count($dump).' ids were dumped into the list.'."\n");
?>
```